# How to use socket in win32

Tags: c, sockets

i have created the socket program to run in win32 service but the problem i'm facing is that when i start the service it'll start and it is using CPU move its all most 50% of the CPU. i'm using AMD 64bit processor.

if i write a program without socket it wont use CPU as much.

wat should i do to solve this problem.

Comment: A *short* sample that shows the problem (runnable as a console) would help.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to look at something like `select()`, to block when waiting for data to read.

Without more detail, it's hard to tell exactly what your problem is, but it's likely to be something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, a piece of sample code would help, but the problem is most likely that you're in a timeout loop.  Depending on which side of the client/server connection you're on, this could be solved by either calling accept() or select() with an infinite timeout.  In practice, it's better to have a long timeout, on the order of a second, so the process/thread can look for a signal and shut down if requested.